# Delete test log file failed in unit test

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, phpunit

During a unit-test, I try to delete a log file which raises the error below

```
ErrorException: unlink(/storage/framework/testing/xxxxxxxxxx.log): Text file busy
```

I have been researching for hours, I could really use some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in development server like (Homestead, ect)?

Comment: Hello,I am using original docker image.

Comment: That erros seems to be a server error like a process or a daemon is accessing that file. Have you tried to reboot the enviroment?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to reboot.

Comment: Fixing some grammar

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm still learning English.